# App or Service to QA 80,000 classified images?

Tags: image-classification, tools, annotation

I've been reviewing services and apps for the past week and my head is exploding.  I just haven't found the right one yet, but I know it has to be out there, so I'm turning to the collective wisdom for help.

We have about 80,000 images that have objects from about 60 classes already tagged.  Most are in VOC format, some are in YOLO.  These were automatically tagged in most cases and we'd like to go through each one to verify the tag, delete images that are irrelevant, change tags when necessary, etc.

I've tried RectLabel on OSX, Dataturks, LabelBox, imglab, and some others.  None really seem to nail it, most are for initial labeling rather than QA/QC.  I'd also be happy to pay a service to do it, but I'm coming up empty on QA services - everyone wants to do the initial labeling.

Any suggestions would be tremendously appreciated.